# Code not executing in child aggregagtor

Tags: trigger, childrecords

I can't understand why I am not getting my debugs in here--

my code is

```
for(AGR_Agreement__c agr:newAgr){
    for(Account acc:agr.Accounts__r){
    system.debug('MVK '+agr.AMS_Agreement__c);
        system.debug('MVK '+agr.Agreement_Status__c);
        system.debug('MVK '+agr.Sub_Service__c);
        system.debug('MVK '+acc.Account_Record_Type__c);

        if(agr.AMS_Agreement__c == true && agr.Agreement_Status__c.equals(deactivatedStatus) && !acc.Account_Record_Type__c.equals(recTypeInternational) 
            && !acc.Account_Record_Type__c.equals(recTypeCandidatePool)){
            acc.Central_purchasing__c = '';
            lstAccounts.add(acc);   
        }                   

        else if(agr.AMS_Agreement__c == true && agr.Agreement_Status__c.equals(applicableStatus) && agr.Sub_Service__c.equals(subServicePriceAgreeement) && !acc.Account_Record_Type__c.equals(recTypeInternational) 
            && !acc.Account_Record_Type__c.equals(recTypeCandidatePool)){
            acc.Central_purchasing__c = agr.Name;
            lstAccounts.add(acc);
        }
        else if(agr.AMS_Agreement__c == false && !agr.Agreement_Status__c.equals(applicableStatus)  && !agr.Sub_Service__c.equals(subServicePriceAgreeement) && !acc.Account_Record_Type__c.equals(recTypeInternational) 
            && !acc.Account_Record_Type__c.equals(recTypeCandidatePool)){
            acc.Central_purchasing__c = '';
            lstAccounts.add(acc);
        }
    }
}
//Since in test classes we are inserting accounts multiple times (parent and child) we cant bypass this trigger as it will make the second account insert not working
if(!Test.isRunningTest()){
    PAD.addTriggerBypass(PAD.TH_ACC_AccountTriggerHandler); //Remove lag by avoiding triggers
}
Database.update(lstAccounts, true);
```

Debug logs--

> |[1407]||Database.QueryLocatorIterator.hasNext() 11:17:58.357
>   (3413210330)|METHOD_EXIT|[1407]||Database.QueryLocatorIterator.hasNext()
>   11:17:58.357
>   (3413214858)|METHOD_ENTRY|[1407]||Database.QueryLocatorIterator.next()
>   11:17:58.357
>   (3413264259)|METHOD_EXIT|[1407]||Database.QueryLocatorIterator.next()
>   11:17:58.357
>   (3413548087)|METHOD_ENTRY|[1407]||Database.QueryLocatorIterator.hasNext()
>   11:17:58.357
>   (3413561139)|METHOD_EXIT|[1407]||Database.QueryLocatorIterator.hasNext()
>   11:17:58.357
>   (3413692191)|METHOD_ENTRY|[1432]||System.Test.isRunningTest()
>   11:17:58.357
>   (3413741766)|METHOD_EXIT|[1432]||System.Test.isRunningTest()
>   11:17:58.357 (3415607798)|METHOD_ENTRY|[1]|01pb0000001hhZp|PAD.PAD()
>   11:17:58.357
>   (3418611641)|METHOD_ENTRY|[152]||System.UserInfo.getName()
>   11:17:58.357 (3418682655)|METHOD_EXIT|[152]||System.UserInfo.getName()
>   11:17:58.357
>   (3418900071)|METHOD_ENTRY|[156]||System.UserInfo.getUserId()
>   11:17:58.357
>   (3418934254)|METHOD_EXIT|[156]||System.UserInfo.getUserId()
>   11:17:58.357
>   (3420734126)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[153]|Aggregations:0|SELECT
>   UserRole.Name, Profile.Name, UserPreferencesApexPagesDeveloperMode,
>   Bypass_Trigger__c, PAD_BypassTrigger__c, LanguageLocaleKey FROM User
>   WHERE Id = :tmpVar1 LIMIT 1 11:17:58.357
>   (3428772309)|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[153]|Rows:1 11:17:58.357
>   (3429806271)|METHOD_EXIT|[1]|PAD 11:17:58.357
>   (3429821586)|METHOD_ENTRY|[1433]|01pb0000001hhZp|PAD.addTriggerBypass(String)
>   11:17:58.357
>   (3429902682)|METHOD_EXIT|[1433]|01pb0000001hhZp|PAD.addTriggerBypass(String)
>   11:17:58.357
>   (3429951734)|DML_BEGIN|[1435]|Op:Update|Type:Account|Rows:2715

so my system debugs are not printing..

can you  please help.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading this right, all the logs are telling us is that when you reach this section of code:

```
for(AGR_Agreement__c agr:newAgr){
    for(Account acc:agr.Accounts__r){
```

`newAgr` contains one `AGR_Agreement__c` and its `Accounts__r` related list is empty. That's what these lines are telling us

> |[1407]||Database.QueryLocatorIterator.hasNext() 11:17:58.357 (3413210330)|METHOD_EXIT|[1407]||Database.QueryLocatorIterator.hasNext() 11:17:58.357 (3413214858)|METHOD_ENTRY|[1407]||Database.QueryLocatorIterator.next() 11:17:58.357 (3413264259)|METHOD_EXIT|[1407]||Database.QueryLocatorIterator.next() 11:17:58.357 (3413548087)|METHOD_ENTRY|[1407]||Database.QueryLocatorIterator.hasNext() 11:17:58.357 (3413561139)|METHOD_EXIT|[1407]||Database.QueryLocatorIterator.hasNext() 11:17:58.357 (3413692191)|METHOD_ENTRY|

`next()` gets called once for the outer loop and zero times for the inner loop.